# How to get user input for client side HTML5 column (array) filtering using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, client

I have a table with many entries (4000 - 5000) with 5 columns. These are paginated and only about 20 rows are shown at a time although all data exists at the client side.

I want the user to filter different column by categories (and if possible using some wildcards), this user input will be taken using something like Form input. Note that i can perform all the operations using Javascript code, however i am unable to understand what kind of UI elements do i need to use for this purpose (I am not from a web dev. background but learning the tricks). I tried using libraries such as selectize, researched some Jquery UI plugins. In fact i also found a spreadsheet specific library (slickgrid.js) but it is slightly beyond my skill to implement.

So in essence is there a simple way to get user input to select categories in a column(s) with all data in client array ? I would love to reach a stage where i may be able to group column categories and use them to give autocomplete/ dropdown menus etc. However i am just trying to figure out a reliable way to translate user input to string to be used in code.

Comment: You get the user to enter values using html form controls such as `<input type="text">` and `<select>`.

Comment: can category options be displayed in the form control ? e.g. Select between A, B, C (and if possible select A & B) etc. ?

Comment: Yes. A `<select multiple>` element will permit that. There are also JS libraries (such as jQuery-UI) that let you provide fancier controls. I suggest you read [a tutorial on html forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FForms) and then come back if you still have questions. Your current question is really too broad to be answered at Stack Overflow.